# How do I fix ReferenceError: command is not defined

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot and I get the error "ReferenceError: command is not defined" I don't understand why, can someone help?

heres my code:

```js
console.clear();
    
const Discord = require('discord.js');
    
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ['GUILDS', 'GUILD_MESSAGES']});

const Client = require("./Structures/Client.js");

const config = require("./Data/config.json");

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const fs = require("fs");

fs.readdirSync("./src/Commands")
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".js"))
  .forEach((file) => {
    /**
     * @type {Command}
     */
    const commands = require(`./Commands/${file}`);
    console.log(`Command ${command.name} loaded`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
  });

client.on("ready", () => console.log("SpidBot is online!"));

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  //console.log(message.content);
//if (message.content == "!Spid") message.reply("Hello!");

if (!message.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

const args = message.content.substring(config.prefix.length).split(/ +/);

const command = client.commands.find((cmd) => cmd.name == args[0]);
});

client.login(config.token);
```

heres the error:

```
C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\src\index.js:22
                  console.log(`Command ${command.name} loaded`);
                                         ^
  
  ReferenceError: command is not defined
      at C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\src\index.js:22:26
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Aly\Desktop\SpidBot\src\index.js:17:3)
      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
      at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
      at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

It appears theres some more errors, so can someone help me fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally misspelt the variable name on line 21:

```
const commands = require(`./Commands/${file}`);
```

You named the variable "command**s**". Simply remove the 's' and it should work.

So it should be:

```
const command = require(`./Commands/${file}`);
```

Comment: @Spademin I'm talking about "const commands", shouldn't it be "const command"?

Comment: Oh sorry, I just tried it and it worked now, thank you so much!